# 10-hole harmonica types

Tags: instruments

Of the many 10-hole harmonicas I have, only one enables me to play almost all of the true notes in a song: It is a hohner I have misplaced which I have had for 40 years. It is one of the few I have seen with stainless steel seperators between each note. It has different notes to a 'blues' type.
Does anyone know what type of tuning I am referring to and what manufactures offer something similar in a 10-hole version?
Thanks 
Trevor